# Malformed function array on PHP7 against Postgresql database

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I have a Postgresql function that receives an array os varchars, like: ['name1','name2']:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.validalista(
    matriculas character varying[])
    RETURNS character varying[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
usern varchar[];
array_final varchar[];

BEGIN   
        foreach usern in array matriculas loop
            SELECT u.username FROM public.mdl_user u WHERE u.username = usern AND u.suspended = 0 into array_final;
             
            RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', usern; 
        end loop;
        return array_final;
end;
$BODY$;
```

And in php I call function like this (main.php):

```
$usernames = array('fabricio.franco', 'guest');
$pdffile->getMatriculas($instancia, $usernames);
```

About lib.php hosting functions:

```
public static function getMatriculas($db, $usernames){
    try{  
        $sql = "SELECT validalista(:arraylista)"; var_dump($db);
        $res = $db->prepare($sql); 
        $res->bindParam(":arraylista", $usernames);
        $res->execute();
        
        echo "Executou sucesso, sucesoooo!";
        
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "-> ". $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

This erros appears:

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: malformed array literal: "Array" DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. CONTEXT: unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'

My real need is verify some student registry strings, from an array. Is this possible with functions, or maybe with php queries?

Comment: Why should `SELECT validalista('fabricio.franco', 'guest')` be a valid query?

Comment: Given this [PHP array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)  I don't see that a PHP array matches up with a Postgres [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html).

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks. I changed varchar[] to anyarray pseudotype and it works. Thanks!